# ROOT_DIR definition seems to change depending on where it is called from (Python os library)

Tags: python, path, filepath

I have a definitions.py file with just this in  it:

```
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

The purpose was to just keep track of my project's root directory so that I could use it in various places in my project without retyping it. I also thought it might help out if I cloned my project to a different location...

However, when I import this `ROOT_DIR` variable in a different file and create these two print statements:

```
 from definitions import ROOT_DIR
 print(ROOT_DIR)
 print(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, '/resampled/high_pitch.wav'))
```

I get out something that doesn't seem right:

```
C:\Users\wesle\PycharmProjects\who-said-what
C:/resampled/high_pitch.wav
```

When the expected output is:

```
C:\Users\wesle\PycharmProjects\who-said-what\resampled\high_pitch.wav
```

I think it might have something to do with this bit in the docs:

> On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path
> component (e.g., r'\foo') is encountered. If a component contains a
> drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive
> letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each
> drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the
> current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

But this explanation is extremely convoluted, making it difficult to tell if it pertains to my problem or not.

Comment: `print(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'resampled/high_pitch.wav'))` - you don't want that leading `/` on the path that you are trying to join to it.

Comment: Interesting. Such a small thing but that fixed it.

Comment: With the leading `/`, the second part is an absolute rather than relative path.

Comment: Thank you @alaniwi. I would have banged my head against this all night and never figured it out.